# "undefined reference to std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator" when returning iterator

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator, set

I'm trying to implement a simple std::find_if() like function to use (I'm not allowed to use it in my homework).

This is my implementation:

```
template<class Iterator, class Function>
Iterator setFindIf(Iterator first, Iterator end, Function predicate) {
    for (Iterator iterator = first; iterator != end; ++iterator) {
        if (predicate(*iterator)) {
            return iterator;
        }
    }
    return end;
}
```

This is the line that calls setFindIf():

```
if (setFindIf(orders.begin(), orders.end(),
            orderCustomerHasOpenOrder(id, ordNum)) != orders.end()) {
```

And this is the error:

```
undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Order> setFindIf<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Order>, orderCustomerHasOpenOrder>(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Order>, std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Order>, orderCustomerHasOpenOrder)'
```

Thanks for helpers.

Comment: My guess is that you've put the template implementation in a source file, and tried to call it from a different source file. [You can't do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021); usually, you need to define templates in headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you declared the template in a header:

```
template<class Iterator, class Function>
Iterator setFindIf(Iterator first, Iterator end, Function predicate);
```

And then put the implementation in a .cpp file, and call it from a different .cpp file. It doesn't work this way with templates.

Mike got there first with his answer, but he made it a comment, so I'm posting this anyway.